# Angular 2 redirect if user is logged in

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

and `AuthGuard`:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

When the user visits the website, he gets redirected to the login page. Same happens when the user tries to access `/dashboard` route without authentication. How can I redirect the user to `/dashboard` if he's logged in? For example, when I visit `myapp.com` and I'm logged in I want to be redirected to `myapp.com/dashboard`.

Comment: Doing this on `canActivate` won't work? `if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) { this.router.navigate(['dashboard']); return true; }`.

Comment: @developer033, I tried, it does not work! There will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Hmm, so you must check it only on your `LoginComponent` (on `ngOnInit`)..

Comment: I think you want to do it the other way around from the root.  You should redirect them to /dashboard, which checks the canActivate, and redirects to login if not already logged in.

Comment: @developer033, This way works!

Comment: @JSess, I don't understand what you mean? I need to create another guard and add it to the root?

Comment: See Dawid's answer, for what I meant ^.^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case I would probably redirect everything to `DashboardComponent` using

`{path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}`

and than the dashboard component can determinate if the user is logged in or not (as it has AuthGuard active), and if the user is not logged in it would redirect him to login.

Comment: While this works, it's backwards and forces you into the "dashboard" flow anytime someone hits your homepage.  The other answer of using `resovle` is much more flexible and keeps you from redirecting all over the place (`/` goes to either `/login` or `/dashboard` instead of `/ -> /dashboard -> /login`

Comment: what if user directly hit `/login` this wont work then

Comment: well, it should be a problem for you if the users visits `/login`, as it's not causing any problems :) But anyways, the answer below will suite you probably.

Answer (score 15):

You want to look at the `resolve` property within the [`Route` interface].

All of the following properties are available to a route:

```ts
export interface Route {
  path?: string;
  pathMatch?: string;
  matcher?: UrlMatcher;
  component?: Type<any>;
  redirectTo?: string;
  outlet?: string;
  canActivate?: any[];
  canActivateChild?: any[];
  canDeactivate?: any[];
  canLoad?: any[];
  data?: Data;
  resolve?: ResolveData;
  children?: Routes;
  loadChildren?: LoadChildren;
  runGuardsAndResolvers?: RunGuardsAndResolvers;
  _loadedConfig?: LoadedRouterConfig;
}
```

`resolve` is designed to allow you to load some type of data *before* proceeding to the route. The signature for `resolve` looks like this:

```ts
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<T>|Promise<T>|T
```

We can ignore that signature, however, and override it because, in this case, we want to redirect to **/dashboard** if the user is *logged in*. Otherwise, display **/login** route normally.

The solution is to create an `injectable` class and attach it to the login route's `resolve` property.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class IsLoggedIn {
  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  resolve(): void {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
  }
}
```

On your **/login** route, add the resolve property.

```ts
{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  resolve: [IsLoggedIn]
}
```

Import the class in `AppModule` and add it to `providers`.

```
providers: [
  IsLoggedIn
]
```

Now anytime a *logged in* user attempts to go to **/login**, they'll be redirected to **/dashboard** without seeing the login page.

Comment: this method redirects sure, but still loads the module!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the quickest thing to do is to tweak your `LoginComponent`.

Given that `this.authService.isLoggedIn()` returns a boolean. In your `LoginComponent` you can quickly check the state in `ngOnInit` as below:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import {AuthService} from '<path_to_your_auth_service>';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _authService: AuthService
  )

  ngOnInit() {
    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this._route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';

    // CHECK THE isLoggedIn STATE HERE 
    if (this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this._router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    }

  }

  // Rest fo the logic here like login etc

  login() { }

}
```

Note that you're only adding this to `ngOnInit`

```
if (this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  this._router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
}
```